# Eval mgrep makes while loop run once

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep

Let's consider these two simple pieace of bash code.

Code A (without eval mgrep):

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
done <<EOF
1234567
2345678
3456789
EOF
```

Code B (with eval mgrep):

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
  eval "mgrep $line"
done <<EOF
1234567
2345678
3456789
EOF
```

After running Code A, I get the expected output, i.e.:

```
1234567
2345678
3456789
```

While running Code B will produce something like:

```
1234567
[...mgrep results here...]
```

So it means, the while loop is only executed for the first input line and not for the remaining ones. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mgrep` reads stdin, exhausting the input.

Comment: @choroba thanks. So how do I solve it?

Comment: What are you trying to `mgrep`?

Comment: @choroba, I need a more complex mgrep in reality, searching for ip addresses, filtering results according to different fields, counting them and putting results together.
But it's not abut what I need to do with grep. The question is how can I make the Code B work as I expect?

Comment: If you provide a filename argument, `mgrep` won't read from stdin.

Comment: @Gpp094 It *is* about what you need to do with `mgrep`, because the entire problem is that it's reading from (/searching) the wrong thing; to solve this, you need to tell `mgrep` the correct thing to search. So what's the correct thing for it to search? BTW, `eval` should be avoided whenever possible -- it makes the shell parsing process even more confusing than it is to begin with, and hence tends to lead to weird bugs.